# c# System.Net.WebException: 'Error on the remote server: (400) Bad Request.' - HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, http

```
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"] + "/Archivador/MoverEnvio";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        if (Certificado != null)
        {
            // Y añadirlo a la petición HTTP
            req.ClientCertificates.Add(Certificado);
        }

        req.Method = "PUT";
        req.ContentType = "application/json";

        ArchivadorModelPut Mover = new ArchivadorModelPut()
        {
            ID_ARCHIVADOR = idArchivador,
            ID_ENVIO = idEnvio

        };
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mover);

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            var dato = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string returnString = resp.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
```

I got this Exception:

> System.Net.WebException: 'Error on the remote server: (400) Bad
>   Request.'

On line:

```
using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
```

I don't know how to resolve the problem, can someone help me?
If you need more information about it, let me know.

Comment: You've just created the request object but you've not invoked it yet.

Answer (score 1):

This exception means that the request was completed successfully, however a [400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) HTTP response was returned. A 400 HTTP response normally means that your client did not send the correct data, however its completely up to the destination server under what circumstances a 400 response would be returned.

If you catch the `WebException` you can use the [Response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx) property to look at the HTTP response - depending on the server it might contain a description of the error.

If its normal practice for the destination service to return a 400 response then take a look at [Why does HttpWebRequest throw an exception instead returning HttpStatusCode.NotFound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081726/why-does-httpwebrequest-throw-an-exception-instead-returning-httpstatuscode-notf) for an extension method that can be used to get the response regardless of the status code. Alternatively you could use an alternative class that doesn't throw, e.g. `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was very helpful! @Justin